# FB Messenger Bot with NodeJS webhook + CasperJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, facebook, casperjs, facebook-messenger-bot

I followed FB's [tutorial](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/guides/quick-start) to make a FB messenger bot. The webhook is made successfully, I now want to move forward to capture Facebook user's input (the message that sends to my page), and use it as an input to my CasperJS script. Last, I would like to use the CasperJS script's output and reply back to the Facebook user.

app.js used in Facebook Messenger Bot (basically it's the same one given by the example, just changed the `sendTextMessage(recipientId, messageText)` function:

```
/*
 * Copyright 2016-present, Facebook, Inc.
 * All rights reserved.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 *
 */

/* jshint node: true, devel: true */
'use strict';

const 
  bodyParser = require('body-parser'),
  config = require('config'),
  crypto = require('crypto'),
  express = require('express'),
  https = require('https'),  
  request = require('request');

var app = express();
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 5000);
app.set('view engine', 'ejs');
app.use(bodyParser.json({ verify: verifyRequestSignature }));
app.use(express.static('public'));

/*
 * Be sure to setup your config values before running this code. You can 
 * set them using environment variables or modifying the config file in /config.
 *
 */

// App Secret can be retrieved from the App Dashboard
const APP_SECRET = (process.env.MESSENGER_APP_SECRET) ? 
  process.env.MESSENGER_APP_SECRET :
  config.get('appSecret');

// Arbitrary value used to validate a webhook
const VALIDATION_TOKEN = (process.env.MESSENGER_VALIDATION_TOKEN) ?
  (process.env.MESSENGER_VALIDATION_TOKEN) :
  config.get('validationToken');

// Generate a page access token for your page from the App Dashboard
const PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN = (process.env.MESSENGER_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN) ?
  (process.env.MESSENGER_PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN) :
  config.get('pageAccessToken');

// URL where the app is running (include protocol). Used to point to scripts and 
// assets located at this address. 
const SERVER_URL = (process.env.SERVER_URL) ?
  (process.env.SERVER_URL) :
  config.get('serverURL');

if (!(APP_SECRET && VALIDATION_TOKEN && PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN && SERVER_URL)) {
  console.error("Missing config values");
  process.exit(1);
}

/*
 * Use your own validation token. Check that the token used in the Webhook 
 * setup is the same token used here.
 *
 */
app.get('/webhook', function(req, res) {
  if (req.query['hub.mode'] === 'subscribe' &&
      req.query['hub.verify_token'] === VALIDATION_TOKEN) {
    console.log("Validating webhook");
    res.status(200).send(req.query['hub.challenge']);
  } else {
    console.error("Failed validation. Make sure the validation tokens match." + VALIDATION_TOKEN + ", " + req.query['hub.verify_token']);
    res.sendStatus(403);          
  }  
});


/*
 * All callbacks for Messenger are POST-ed. They will be sent to the same
 * webhook. Be sure to subscribe your app to your page to receive callbacks
 * for your page. 
 * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/product-overview/setup#subscribe_app
 *
 */
app.post('/webhook', function (req, res) {
  var data = req.body;

  // Make sure this is a page subscription
  if (data.object == 'page') {
    // Iterate over each entry
    // There may be multiple if batched
    data.entry.forEach(function(pageEntry) {
      var pageID = pageEntry.id;
      var timeOfEvent = pageEntry.time;

      // Iterate over each messaging event
      pageEntry.messaging.forEach(function(messagingEvent) {
        if (messagingEvent.optin) {
          receivedAuthentication(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.message) {
          receivedMessage(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.delivery) {
          receivedDeliveryConfirmation(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.postback) {
          receivedPostback(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.read) {
          receivedMessageRead(messagingEvent);
        } else if (messagingEvent.account_linking) {
          receivedAccountLink(messagingEvent);
        } else {
          console.log("Webhook received unknown messagingEvent: ", messagingEvent);
        }
      });
    });

    // Assume all went well.
    //
    // You must send back a 200, within 20 seconds, to let us know you've 
    // successfully received the callback. Otherwise, the request will time out.
    res.sendStatus(200);
  }
});

/*
 * This path is used for account linking. The account linking call-to-action
 * (sendAccountLinking) is pointed to this URL. 
 * 
 */
app.get('/authorize', function(req, res) {
  var accountLinkingToken = req.query.account_linking_token;
  var redirectURI = req.query.redirect_uri;

  // Authorization Code should be generated per user by the developer. This will 
  // be passed to the Account Linking callback.
  var authCode = "1234567890";

  // Redirect users to this URI on successful login
  var redirectURISuccess = redirectURI + "&authorization_code=" + authCode;

  res.render('authorize', {
    accountLinkingToken: accountLinkingToken,
    redirectURI: redirectURI,
    redirectURISuccess: redirectURISuccess
  });
});

/*
 * Verify that the callback came from Facebook. Using the App Secret from 
 * the App Dashboard, we can verify the signature that is sent with each 
 * callback in the x-hub-signature field, located in the header.
 *
 * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks#setup
 *
 */
function verifyRequestSignature(req, res, buf) {
  var signature = req.headers["x-hub-signature"];

  if (!signature) {
    // For testing, let's log an error. In production, you should throw an 
    // error.
    console.error("Couldn't validate the signature.");
  } else {
    var elements = signature.split('=');
    var method = elements[0];
    var signatureHash = elements[1];

    var expectedHash = crypto.createHmac('sha1', APP_SECRET)
                        .update(buf)
                        .digest('hex');

    if (signatureHash != expectedHash) {
      throw new Error("Couldn't validate the request signature.");
    }
  }
}

/*
 * Authorization Event
 *
 * The value for 'optin.ref' is defined in the entry point. For the "Send to 
 * Messenger" plugin, it is the 'data-ref' field. Read more at 
 * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/authentication
 *
 */
function receivedAuthentication(event) {
  var senderID = event.sender.id;
  var recipientID = event.recipient.id;
  var timeOfAuth = event.timestamp;

  // The 'ref' field is set in the 'Send to Messenger' plugin, in the 'data-ref'
  // The developer can set this to an arbitrary value to associate the 
  // authentication callback with the 'Send to Messenger' click event. This is
  // a way to do account linking when the user clicks the 'Send to Messenger' 
  // plugin.
  var passThroughParam = event.optin.ref;

  console.log("Received authentication for user %d and page %d with pass " +
    "through param '%s' at %d", senderID, recipientID, passThroughParam, 
    timeOfAuth);

  // When an authentication is received, we'll send a message back to the sender
  // to let them know it was successful.
  sendTextMessage(senderID, "Authentication successful");
}

/*
 * Message Event
 *
 * This event is called when a message is sent to your page. The 'message' 
 * object format can vary depending on the kind of message that was received.
 * Read more at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message-received
 *
 * For this example, we're going to echo any text that we get. If we get some 
 * special keywords ('button', 'generic', 'receipt'), then we'll send back
 * examples of those bubbles to illustrate the special message bubbles we've 
 * created. If we receive a message with an attachment (image, video, audio), 
 * then we'll simply confirm that we've received the attachment.
 * 
 */
function receivedMessage(event) {
  var senderID = event.sender.id;
  var recipientID = event.recipient.id;
  var timeOfMessage = event.timestamp;
  var message = event.message;

  console.log("Received message for user %d and page %d at %d with message:", 
    senderID, recipientID, timeOfMessage);
  console.log(JSON.stringify(message));

  var isEcho = message.is_echo;
  var messageId = message.mid;
  var appId = message.app_id;
  var metadata = message.metadata;

  // You may get a text or attachment but not both
  var messageText = message.text;
  var messageAttachments = message.attachments;
  var quickReply = message.quick_reply;

  if (isEcho) {
    // Just logging message echoes to console
    console.log("Received echo for message %s and app %d with metadata %s", 
      messageId, appId, metadata);
    return;
  } else if (quickReply) {
    var quickReplyPayload = quickReply.payload;
    console.log("Quick reply for message %s with payload %s",
      messageId, quickReplyPayload);

    sendTextMessage(senderID, "Quick reply tapped");
    return;
  }

  if (messageText) {

    // If we receive a text message, check to see if it matches any special
    // keywords and send back the corresponding example. Otherwise, just echo
    // the text we received.
    switch (messageText) {
      case 'image':
        sendImageMessage(senderID);
        break;

      case 'gif':
        sendGifMessage(senderID);
        break;

      case 'audio':
        sendAudioMessage(senderID);
        break;

      case 'video':
        sendVideoMessage(senderID);
        break;

      case 'file':
        sendFileMessage(senderID);
        break;

      case 'button':
        sendButtonMessage(senderID);
        break;

      case 'generic':
        sendGenericMessage(senderID);
        break;

      case 'receipt':
        sendReceiptMessage(senderID);
        break;

      case 'quick reply':
        sendQuickReply(senderID);
        break;        

      case 'read receipt':
        sendReadReceipt(senderID);
        break;        

      case 'typing on':
        sendTypingOn(senderID);
        break;        

      case 'typing off':
        sendTypingOff(senderID);
        break;        

      case 'account linking':
        sendAccountLinking(senderID);
        break;

      default:
        sendTextMessage(senderID, messageText);
    }
  } else if (messageAttachments) {
    sendTextMessage(senderID, "Message with attachment received");
  }
}


/*
 * Delivery Confirmation Event
 *
 * This event is sent to confirm the delivery of a message. Read more about 
 * these fields at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message-delivered
 *
 */
function receivedDeliveryConfirmation(event) {
  var senderID = event.sender.id;
  var recipientID = event.recipient.id;
  var delivery = event.delivery;
  var messageIDs = delivery.mids;
  var watermark = delivery.watermark;
  var sequenceNumber = delivery.seq;

  if (messageIDs) {
    messageIDs.forEach(function(messageID) {
      console.log("Received delivery confirmation for message ID: %s", 
        messageID);
    });
  }

  console.log("All message before %d were delivered.", watermark);
}


/*
 * Postback Event
 *
 * This event is called when a postback is tapped on a Structured Message. 
 * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/postback-received
 * 
 */
function receivedPostback(event) {
  var senderID = event.sender.id;
  var recipientID = event.recipient.id;
  var timeOfPostback = event.timestamp;

  // The 'payload' param is a developer-defined field which is set in a postback 
  // button for Structured Messages. 
  var payload = event.postback.payload;

  console.log("Received postback for user %d and page %d with payload '%s' " + 
    "at %d", senderID, recipientID, payload, timeOfPostback);

  // When a postback is called, we'll send a message back to the sender to 
  // let them know it was successful
  sendTextMessage(senderID, "Postback called");
}

/*
 * Message Read Event
 *
 * This event is called when a previously-sent message has been read.
 * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/message-read
 * 
 */
function receivedMessageRead(event) {
  var senderID = event.sender.id;
  var recipientID = event.recipient.id;

  // All messages before watermark (a timestamp) or sequence have been seen.
  var watermark = event.read.watermark;
  var sequenceNumber = event.read.seq;

  console.log("Received message read event for watermark %d and sequence " +
    "number %d", watermark, sequenceNumber);
}

/*
 * Account Link Event
 *
 * This event is called when the Link Account or UnLink Account action has been
 * tapped.
 * https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/webhook-reference/account-linking
 * 
 */
function receivedAccountLink(event) {
  var senderID = event.sender.id;
  var recipientID = event.recipient.id;

  var status = event.account_linking.status;
  var authCode = event.account_linking.authorization_code;

  console.log("Received account link event with for user %d with status %s " +
    "and auth code %s ", senderID, status, authCode);
}

/*
 * Send an image using the Send API.
 *
 */
function sendImageMessage(recipientId) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      attachment: {
        type: "image",
        payload: {
          url: SERVER_URL + "/assets/rift.png"
        }
      }
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Send a Gif using the Send API.
 *
 */
function sendGifMessage(recipientId) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      attachment: {
        type: "image",
        payload: {
          url: SERVER_URL + "/assets/instagram_logo.gif"
        }
      }
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Send audio using the Send API.
 *
 */
function sendAudioMessage(recipientId) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      attachment: {
        type: "audio",
        payload: {
          url: SERVER_URL + "/assets/sample.mp3"
        }
      }
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Send a video using the Send API.
 *
 */
function sendVideoMessage(recipientId) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      attachment: {
        type: "video",
        payload: {
          url: SERVER_URL + "/assets/allofus480.mov"
        }
      }
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Send a file using the Send API.
 *
 */
function sendFileMessage(recipientId) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      attachment: {
        type: "file",
        payload: {
          url: SERVER_URL + "/assets/test.txt"
        }
      }
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Send a text message using the Send API.
 *
 */
function sendTextMessage(recipientId, messageText) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      text: "{The data fed from CasperJS}",
      metadata: "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_METADATA"
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Send a button message using the Send API.
 *
 */
function sendButtonMessage(recipientId) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      attachment: {
        type: "template",
        payload: {
          template_type: "button",
          text: "This is test text",
          buttons:[{
            type: "web_url",
            url: "https://www.oculus.com/en-us/rift/",
            title: "Open Web URL"
          }, {
            type: "postback",
            title: "Trigger Postback",
            payload: "DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD"
          }, {
            type: "phone_number",
            title: "Call Phone Number",
            payload: "+16505551234"
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  };  

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Send a Structured Message (Generic Message type) using the Send API.
 *
 */
function sendGenericMessage(recipientId) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      attachment: {
        type: "template",
        payload: {
          template_type: "generic",
          elements: [{
            title: "rift",
            subtitle: "Next-generation virtual reality",
            item_url: "https://www.oculus.com/en-us/rift/",               
            image_url: SERVER_URL + "/assets/rift.png",
            buttons: [{
              type: "web_url",
              url: "https://www.oculus.com/en-us/rift/",
              title: "Open Web URL"
            }, {
              type: "postback",
              title: "Call Postback",
              payload: "Payload for first bubble",
            }],
          }, {
            title: "touch",
            subtitle: "Your Hands, Now in VR",
            item_url: "https://www.oculus.com/en-us/touch/",               
            image_url: SERVER_URL + "/assets/touch.png",
            buttons: [{
              type: "web_url",
              url: "https://www.oculus.com/en-us/touch/",
              title: "Open Web URL"
            }, {
              type: "postback",
              title: "Call Postback",
              payload: "Payload for second bubble",
            }]
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  };  

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Send a receipt message using the Send API.
 *
 */
function sendReceiptMessage(recipientId) {
  // Generate a random receipt ID as the API requires a unique ID
  var receiptId = "order" + Math.floor(Math.random()*1000);

  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message:{
      attachment: {
        type: "template",
        payload: {
          template_type: "receipt",
          recipient_name: "Peter Chang",
          order_number: receiptId,
          currency: "USD",
          payment_method: "Visa 1234",        
          timestamp: "1428444852", 
          elements: [{
            title: "Oculus Rift",
            subtitle: "Includes: headset, sensor, remote",
            quantity: 1,
            price: 599.00,
            currency: "USD",
            image_url: SERVER_URL + "/assets/riftsq.png"
          }, {
            title: "Samsung Gear VR",
            subtitle: "Frost White",
            quantity: 1,
            price: 99.99,
            currency: "USD",
            image_url: SERVER_URL + "/assets/gearvrsq.png"
          }],
          address: {
            street_1: "1 Hacker Way",
            street_2: "",
            city: "Menlo Park",
            postal_code: "94025",
            state: "CA",
            country: "US"
          },
          summary: {
            subtotal: 698.99,
            shipping_cost: 20.00,
            total_tax: 57.67,
            total_cost: 626.66
          },
          adjustments: [{
            name: "New Customer Discount",
            amount: -50
          }, {
            name: "$100 Off Coupon",
            amount: -100
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Send a message with Quick Reply buttons.
 *
 */
function sendQuickReply(recipientId) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      text: "What's your favorite movie genre?",
      quick_replies: [
        {
          "content_type":"text",
          "title":"Action",
          "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_ACTION"
        },
        {
          "content_type":"text",
          "title":"Comedy",
          "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_COMEDY"
        },
        {
          "content_type":"text",
          "title":"Drama",
          "payload":"DEVELOPER_DEFINED_PAYLOAD_FOR_PICKING_DRAMA"
        }
      ]
    }
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Send a read receipt to indicate the message has been read
 *
 */
function sendReadReceipt(recipientId) {
  console.log("Sending a read receipt to mark message as seen");

  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    sender_action: "mark_seen"
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Turn typing indicator on
 *
 */
function sendTypingOn(recipientId) {
  console.log("Turning typing indicator on");

  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    sender_action: "typing_on"
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Turn typing indicator off
 *
 */
function sendTypingOff(recipientId) {
  console.log("Turning typing indicator off");

  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    sender_action: "typing_off"
  };

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Send a message with the account linking call-to-action
 *
 */
function sendAccountLinking(recipientId) {
  var messageData = {
    recipient: {
      id: recipientId
    },
    message: {
      attachment: {
        type: "template",
        payload: {
          template_type: "button",
          text: "Welcome. Link your account.",
          buttons:[{
            type: "account_link",
            url: SERVER_URL + "/authorize"
          }]
        }
      }
    }
  };  

  callSendAPI(messageData);
}

/*
 * Call the Send API. The message data goes in the body. If successful, we'll 
 * get the message id in a response 
 *
 */
function callSendAPI(messageData) {
  request({
    uri: 'https://graph.facebook.com/v2.6/me/messages',
    qs: { access_token: PAGE_ACCESS_TOKEN },
    method: 'POST',
    json: messageData

  }, function (error, response, body) {
    if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
      var recipientId = body.recipient_id;
      var messageId = body.message_id;

      if (messageId) {
        console.log("Successfully sent message with id %s to recipient %s", 
          messageId, recipientId);
      } else {
      console.log("Successfully called Send API for recipient %s", 
        recipientId);
      }
    } else {
      console.error("Failed calling Send API", response.statusCode, response.statusMessage, body.error);
    }
  });  
}

// Start server
// Webhooks must be available via SSL with a certificate signed by a valid 
// certificate authority.
app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});

module.exports = app;
```

The CasperJS script (`echo.js`) that accepts parameter and process it:

```
var casper = require("casper").create();
if(casper.cli.has(0)) {
    casper.echo("Received " + casper.cli.get(0));
}
casper.exit();
```

which I now use the following command to execute it:

```
casperjs echo.js input
```

which will reply:

> Received input

I want this "Received input" thing replied back to the Facebook user. How can I achieve this? How can I connect these components?

Thanks.

Comment: How you send messages is clearly described in the documentation - so, what is your specific question here …?

Comment: Hello @CBroe, my question is, how can I link up CasperJS with NodeJS webhook? Can CasperJS and NodeJS work together? The scenario would be: Received a message via webhook > send request to CasperJS > CasperJS scraps data from other sites > send response to webhook > send the response in form of FB message to FB user via webhook

Comment: I found a thing called [SpookyJS](https://github.com/SpookyJS/SpookyJS), seems relevant, but not sure. I'm now checking on it.

Comment: Why does your bot need to scrape info from other sites? That is likely to increase the response times of your bot considerably.

Comment: Because this is the objective of this bot. Can I reply the user once the scrap action is complete?

Comment: Yeah, answering with a short delay is not a problem from the technical standpoint.

Comment: However, reading from the comments in `app.js`: *You must send back a 200, within 20 seconds, to let us know you've successfully received the callback. Otherwise, the request will time out.* If my scrap action is more than 20 seconds, the request will fail. Any strategy to tackle this limit?

Comment: You only have to acknowledge that you successfully received the request. So if you have to perform actions that might take longer, maybe put those into a background request, that then sends a response to the user once ready.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could run your casper work in some kind of async task ([like a promise](https://gist.github.com/dlukes/54f091daff585b085ce597dae6bd1958)) or [in a background job](http://billpatrianakos.me/blog/2015/07/23/running-background-jobs-with-express/).

You could send the sender's id and the text or whatever you're processing (can't tell from your source code) to the background job or task and respond with your messenger client in the job with the processed, scraped data.

It might also be nice to say "Hey user, I'm scraping some stuff, it'll just be a second" before you respond with the processed data, for a better UX.
[A `typing_on` message](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/messenger-platform/send-api-reference/sender-actions) may also be nice here but YMMV.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. YMMV = Your Milage May Vary, right?